Identifying compatible fluids?
When you inspect your vehicle owner's manual, it will usually specify brand-specific coolants, transmission fluids, gear oils, and motor oils. While motor oils are more universally specified, one can quickly find the right oil for their vehicle by checking the weight, and a few exceptional cases. On the other hand, transmission fluids for example have no unified spec to cross reference and confirm you have identified a compatible fluid. Auto-parts catalogues will provide about 7 or 8 brand alternatives, whereas the owner's manual gives stern warnings against using the wrong fluids for the service.
So which is it? Can we trust the auto parts store catelogues? Or is the manual correct that the precise molecular weight, detergents, pH etc. can only be trusted in the manual's specified (usually costlier) fluid?
As an example, I changed automatic transmission fluid in a Mazda 3. The original fluid was probably 14 years old and at 70,000 miles, and
completely shot. Once I did a change, the operation was noticeably better, but I'm concerned and this spectre of "transmission damage" from using the "wrong fluid".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_transmission_fluid has some info on various specs.
